# How to extract classes from prefetched dataset in Tensorflow for confusion matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I was trying to plot a confusion matrix for my image classifier with the following code but I got an error message: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'

```
Y_pred = model.predict(validation_dataset)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_dataset.classes, y_pred)) # ERROR message generated
```

> PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** this won't work for shuffled datasets.

You can use `tf.stack` to concatenate all the dataset values. Like so:

```
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)
```

For reproducibility, let's say you have a dataset, a neural network, and a training loop:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

data, info = tfds.load('iris', split='train',
                       as_supervised=True,
                       shuffle_files=True,
                       with_info=True)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_dataset = data.take(120).batch(4).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = data.skip(120).take(30).batch(4).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(info.features['label'].num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics='accuracy')

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

Now that your model has been fitted, you can predict the test set:

```
y_pred = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

```
array([[2.2177568e-05, 3.0841196e-01, 6.9156587e-01],
       [4.3539176e-06, 1.2779665e-01, 8.7219906e-01],
       [1.0816366e-03, 9.2667454e-01, 7.2243840e-02],
       [9.9921310e-01, 7.8686583e-04, 9.8775059e-09]], dtype=float32)
```

This is going to be a `(n_samples, 3)` array because we're working with three categories. We want a `(n_samples, 1)` array for `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`, so take the argmax:

```
predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(30,), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2,
       1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)>
```

Then, we can take all the `y` values from the prefetch dataset:

```
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)
```

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 0], dtype=int64)>]
```

Then, you are ready to get the confusion matrix:

```
confusion_matrix(predicted_categories, true_categories)
```

```
array([[ 9,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  9,  0],
       [ 0,  2, 10]], dtype=int64)
```

`(9 + 9 + 10) / 30 = 0.933` is the accuracy score. It corresponds to `model.evaluate(test_dataset)`:

```
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 785us/step - loss: 0.1907 - accuracy: 0.9333
```

Also the results are consistent with `sklearn.metrics.classification_report`:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0       1.00      1.00      1.00         8
           1       0.82      1.00      0.90         9
           2       1.00      0.85      0.92        13
    accuracy                           0.93        30
   macro avg       0.94      0.95      0.94        30
weighted avg       0.95      0.93      0.93        30
```

Here's the entire code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

data, info = tfds.load('iris', split='train',
                       as_supervised=True,
                       shuffle_files=True,
                       with_info=True)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_dataset = data.take(120).batch(4).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = data.skip(120).take(30).batch(4).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(info.features['label'].num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics='accuracy')

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs=50, verbose=0)

y_pred = model.predict(test_dataset)

predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)

confusion_matrix(predicted_categories, true_categories)
```

More generally, you can plot a confusion matrix with [`sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions).

Comment: @Nicholas Sir, thank you, it works but it's not working as expected... model.evaluate() returns an accuracy of 0.82 while the accuracy in the classification report is 0.20 using the same method as you mentioned...

Comment: what is a _classification report_? See my updated answer. It does correspond to the results of `model.evaluate()`.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know that `mode.evaluate()` returns `(loss, accuracy)` right?

Comment: @Nicholas  classification report refers to sklearn.metrics.classification_report. The accuracy returned by model.evaluate(test.dataset) is different from the accuracy returned by the classification report for my case

Comment: @Nicholas yup, I know

Comment: For me the results are the same. I'm not sure what I can do about that. Also please write my name correctly.

Comment: oops! sorry about that. I'll check my code again. Thanks

Comment: Without shuffle it works as expected. But with shuffle e.g. `train_dataset = data.take(120).shuffle(120).batch(4).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)` the results of confusion matrix became strange (close to random), while the training accuracy and loss is normal.

Comment: This code does not support the case with shuffled datasets, and that is the reason @zZzZ is getting strange results.

Comment: @shahryar that makes a lot of sense, I'll update the answer when I get the chance

Comment: there is nothing in the answer that answers the plotting part of the question...

Comment: @Feline you're right, but the content of the question didn't match the title. OP was trying to get the labels to put in his own (undefined) function. I didn't realize this question reached so many views, so I'll edit the question and my answer to correct the misunderstanding

Answer (score 17):

This code will work with shuffled tf.data.Dataset

```
y_pred = []  # store predicted labels
y_true = []  # store true labels

# iterate over the dataset
for image_batch, label_batch in dataset:   # use dataset.unbatch() with repeat
   # append true labels
   y_true.append(label_batch)
   # compute predictions
   preds = model.predict(image_batch)
   # append predicted labels
   y_pred.append(np.argmax(preds, axis = - 1))

# convert the true and predicted labels into tensors
correct_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_true], axis = 0)
predicted_labels = tf.concat([item for item in y_pred], axis = 0)
```

Comment: This code worked well with the shuffled image_dataset_from_directory dataset but the answer with more votes didn't due to shuffling. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works better to handle the shuffling executed by `image_dataset_from_directory`. Thanks!

Comment: this is the correct answer due to handling the shuffle.

Comment: I have a question.

What does data set in for loop mean?

I created an image classification model using TensorFlow. 

The dataset was created using image_dataset_from_directory and is divided into three types: train_ds, val_ds and test_ds.

What does the dataset inside the for loop mean (train_ds, val_ds, test_ds? 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does "use dataset.unbatch() with repeat" mean?