# How can I plot a confusion matrix for image dataset from directory?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

[image]

[image]

I've built up my own neural model, trained it, and got 99.58% accuracy. But I am facing a problem with plotting the confusion matrix. There are some examples available for flow_from_directory but no examples exist for image_dataset_from_directory. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

See the post [How to plot confusion matrix for prefetched dataset in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622210/how-to-plot-confusion-matrix-for-prefetched-dataset-in-tensorflow) using

```py
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
```

to get the true labels for the validation set. Then you can plot the confusion matrix with something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(true_categories, predicted_id)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
sns.set(font_scale=1.4) #for label size
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 12},
     cbar = False, cmap='Purples');
ax1.set_ylabel('True Values',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('Predicted Values',fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where does `predicted_id` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I created to be able to assemble the matrix of confusion

Note:
test_dataset is a tf.data.Dataset variable.
I used validation_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_true = []
y_pred = []
for x,y in validation_dataset:
  y= tf.argmax(y,axis=1)
  y_true.append(y)
  y_pred.append(tf.argmax(model.predict(x),axis = 1))
  
y_pred = tf.concat(y_pred, axis=0)
y_true = tf.concat(y_true, axis=0)
```